# Can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy When trying to enumerate through torch.utils.data.DataLoader object

Tags: python, pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

I tried to run a [multilayer perceptron (MLP) regression model written in PyTorch](https://github.com/christianversloot/machine-learning-articles/blob/main/how-to-create-a-neural-network-for-regression-with-pytorch.md#creating-a-mlp-regression-model-with-pytorch) through GPU in Google Colab. However, I encountered a bunch of errors with different approaches. Below is the code that works fine for CPU.

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
# from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


class BostonDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
  '''
  Prepare the Boston dataset for regression
  '''
  def __init__(self, X, y, scale_data=True):
    if not torch.is_tensor(X) and not torch.is_tensor(y):
      # Apply scaling if necessary
      if scale_data:
          X = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
      self.X = torch.from_numpy(X)
      self.y = torch.from_numpy(y)

  def __len__(self):
      return len(self.X)

  def __getitem__(self, i):
      return self.X[i], self.y[i]


class MLP(nn.Module):
  '''
    Multilayer Perceptron for regression.
  '''
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.layers = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Linear(13, 64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(64, 32),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Linear(32, 1)
    )

  def forward(self, x):
    '''
      Forward pass
    '''
    return self.layers(x)


if __name__ == '__main__':

  # Set fixed random number seed
  torch.manual_seed(42)

  # Load Boston dataset
  # X, y = load_boston(return_X_y=True)
  data_url = "http://lib.stat.cmu.edu/datasets/boston"
  raw_df = pd.read_csv(data_url, sep="\s+", skiprows=22, header=None)
  X = np.hstack([raw_df.values[::2, :], raw_df.values[1::2, :2]])
  y = raw_df.values[1::2, 2]

  # Prepare Boston dataset
  dataset = BostonDataset(X, y)
  trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, num_workers=1)

  # Initialize the MLP
  mlp = MLP()

  # Define the loss function and optimizer
  loss_function = nn.L1Loss()
  optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(mlp.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

  # Run the training loop
  for epoch in range(0, 5): # 5 epochs at maximum

    # Print epoch
    print(f'Starting epoch {epoch+1}')

    # Set current loss value
    current_loss = 0.0

    # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):

      # Get and prepare inputs
      inputs, targets = data
      inputs, targets = inputs.float(), targets.float()
      targets = targets.reshape((targets.shape[0], 1))

      # Zero the gradients
      optimizer.zero_grad()

      # Perform forward pass
      outputs = mlp(inputs)

      # Compute loss
      loss = loss_function(outputs, targets)

      # Perform backward pass
      loss.backward()

      # Perform optimization
      optimizer.step()

      # Print statistics
      current_loss += loss.item()
      if i % 10 == 0:
          print('Loss after mini-batch %5d: %.3f' %
                (i + 1, current_loss / 500))
          current_loss = 0.0

  # Process is complete.
  print('Training process has finished.')
```

**My questions are as follows:**

1. **What's wrong with the current approach shown below and how to fix it?**
2. **Are there any general rules for running a model on GPU?**

- **Should I specify the device globally at the very beginning? If so, why did the initial approach not work?**
- **Should I specfiy the device for each new-defined tensor & model and loaded data?**

I started with setting the default device to GPU at the very beginning:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
torch.set_default_device(device)
```

but it has the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8054e92f6fef> in <cell line: 59>()
     94 
     95     # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
---> 96     for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
     97 
     98       # Get and prepare inputs

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_device.py in __torch_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
     75         if func in _device_constructors() and kwargs.get('device') is None:
     76             kwargs['device'] = self.device
---> 77         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79 # NB: This is directly called from C++ in torch/csrc/Device.cpp

RuntimeError: Expected a 'cuda' device type for generator but found 'cpu'
```

Then I tried to specify the device for model and data one by one because I realized that variable `dataset` is not on GPU even if I set the default device to GPU. Below are my modifications:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
...
self.X = torch.from_numpy(X).to(device)
self.y = torch.from_numpy(y).to(device)
...
self.layers = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(13, 64), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(64, 32), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(32, 1)).to(device)
```

but it has the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-be16076aba77> in <cell line: 55>()
     86 
     87     # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
---> 88     for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
     89 
     90       # Get and prepare inputs

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_device.py in __torch_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
     75         if func in _device_constructors() and kwargs.get('device') is None:
     76             kwargs['device'] = self.device
---> 77         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79 # NB: This is directly called from C++ in torch/csrc/Device.cpp

RuntimeError: Expected a 'cuda' device type for generator but found 'cpu'
```

I did some search and made the following modification:

```
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, num_workers=1, generator=torch.Generator(device=device))
```

but it has the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-24d5f71c82a6> in <cell line: 55>()
     86 
     87     # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
---> 88     for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
     89 
     90       # Get and prepare inputs

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_device.py in __torch_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
     75         if func in _device_constructors() and kwargs.get('device') is None:
     76             kwargs['device'] = self.device
---> 77         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79 # NB: This is directly called from C++ in torch/csrc/Device.cpp

TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

I searched a lot but people have this problem when they try to plot something. I don't know why I have the same problem when trying to enumerate through `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` object. Nevertheless I tried one final thing (on top of the original CPU version) that only applies `.to(device)` to data in the training loop and hoped at least there is no error during the enumeration:

```
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
...
self.layers = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(13, 64), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(64, 32), nn.ReLU(), nn.Linear(32, 1)).to(device)
...
inputs, targets = inputs.float().to(device), targets.float().to(device)
```

But it gives a similar error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-cf2797cc4e83> in <cell line: 55>()
     86 
     87     # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
---> 88     for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
     89 
     90       # Get and prepare inputs

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/_device.py in __torch_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
     75         if func in _device_constructors() and kwargs.get('device') is None:
     76             kwargs['device'] = self.device
---> 77         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     78 
     79 # NB: This is directly called from C++ in torch/csrc/Device.cpp

RuntimeError: Expected a 'cuda' device type for generator but found 'cpu'
```

I have been trying for hours and really appreciate any help on this problem!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.